# how to know if a string is inside an array on Android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, search

Hi everybody im programming an application in Android and I don`t know what to do to get this that I am trying. I now that it is very simple but please  help me!

Lets say that I have an array:

```
String coco[] = { "hi", "everybody", "superman", "batman" };
```

And also I have a:

```
 String heroe = "superman";
```

Now I need to make a loop, method or whatever, that takes "heroe" and search if that value ("superman") its inside the array and then so if that value exist TRUE and if don`t exist FALSE.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most comfortable way is to **convert** the array **to a list** and search then.

It is **clean, short and expressive**.

```
boolean isThere = Arrays.asList(yourArray).contains("needle");
```

Comment: The most elegant solution. +1

Comment: Hey thanks! It really work! clean, short and do the job. I just add if(Arrays.asList(yourArray).contains("String to search") == true){

Comment: @RobertoZuniga glad to hear. By the way, you can omit the `== true` .

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0;i<coco.length;i++)
{
    if(coco[i].equals(heroe))
       return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution. It would be easier to use an ArrayList that can use .contains ()method.

```
for(int i = 0; i < coco.length; i++)
{
        if(coco[i].equals(heroe))
        {
            // a match!
            return true;
        }
}

// no match
return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply iterate over the values in the array and compare them to the value you're looking for

```
public boolean arraySearch(String[] strArray, String key) {

    for (String s : strArray) {
        if (s.equals(key)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can use this by calling `arraySearch(coco, heroe);` in your code.

Alternatively you could use the [Arrays](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html) class and use:

```
boolean keyPresent = Arrays.asList(coco).contains(heroe);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

Just take a variable which you want to search and iterate the array and use `equals` method.

```
String heroe = "superman";
boolean flag = false;
for(int index = 0; index < coco.length; index++)
{
    Strin value = coco[index];
    if(heroe.equals(value))
    {
       flag = true;
    }
}

if(flag) {
   //Exist
}
else {
   //Not Exist 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do some thing like this:

```
    for (String testcoco : coco)
    {
        if (testcoco.contains("superman"))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
```

Comment: the `;` on the if statement line closes the statement, meaning that the first iteration will always return true. You're also missing parenthesis around the `if` conditional.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean checkPresence(String desired)
 for(String s:coco){
    if(s.equals(desired)){
       return true
       }
    }
    return false;
```